# How to unit test PanResponder in React Native?

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I am working on a React Native component handling gestures via PanResponder.

I would like to test that when certain *dx*, *dy* values are passed to the `onPanResponderRelease` method, expected action will be executed. Please find below an example of what I would like to test:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this._panResponder = this._initPanResponder();
  }

  _initPanResponder(): PanResponder {
    const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
        null,
        { dx: this._animation.x, dy: this._animation.y }
      ]),
      onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState) => {
        const { dx, dy } = gestureState;

        if (dy > 100) {
          doSomething(); // <---- what I would like to unit test
        }
      }
    });
    return panResponder;
  }
}
```

Is there any straightforward way to unit test the following with Jest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to leave testing the wiring code out, since testing an actual PanResponder involves a UI test that is hard to write, is usually flaky, and gives little value.

What you can do, is extract the event handling function out, and test it independently.

In that case, the test would very simple, as all you need to do is invoke the handler in the test and see you're getting what you expected.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense! I was somehow hoping there would be a way to simulate gesture. But as you said, I am not sure it brings that much value (especially in the scope of unit testing). The only downside I see is that I'll have to export that event handling function (while it wasn't before) in order to call it directly from the test.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test user's interection with the component you should mock `PanResponder` in a way you forward the functions given as params to `PanResponder.create` to the `panHandlers` it returns.

```
// setup-tests.ts

jest.doMock('react-native', () => {
  return Object.setPrototypeOf(
      PanResponder: {
        ...ReactNative.PanResponder,
        create: (config: any) => ({ panHandlers: config }),
      },
    },
    ReactNative
  );
});
```

Tha way, when yoou spread `panHandlers` in the View you are handling Pan, you can access the functions the way you set up in the file

```
// pan-handling-component.tsx

const Component: React.FC = () => {
...

  const panResponder = React.useRef(
      PanResponder.create({
        ...
        onPanResponderMove: (_, gestureState) => {
          Animated.event([slideAnim], { useNativeDriver: false })(
            gestureState.moveY
          );
        },
        onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true,
        onPanResponderRelease: () => {
          // @ts-ignore
          const currentValue = slideAnim._value;

          if (currentValue < 0) {
            slideIn();
          } else if (currentValue > height - 300) {
            handleClose();
          }
        },
      })
    ).current;

...

    return (

      <View
         testID={DRAWER_WRAPPER_TESTID}
         {...panResponder.panHandlers}
      > 
        ...
      </View>

    );
```

And, finally, the unit test would be something like this

```
// pan-handling-component.test.tsx

...

    const panHandler = instance.root.findByProps({
      testID: DRAWER_WRAPPER_TESTID,
    });

    act(() => {
      panHandler.props.onPanResponderMove(eventMock, gestureStateMOck);
      panHandler.props.onPanResponderRelease();
    });


...
```